# Running a command line for groovy from XCode after unit testing

Tags: xcode, shell, unit-testing, groovy

I edited my target scheme to run a script action after testing as below
    Target Scheme -> Test (Debug) -> Post Actions

[image]

The script hw.sh had a simple command line call:

```
open /Applications/Safari.app/
```

It worked fine for the above script. When I changed it to the following

```
groovy http://frankencover.it/with -s /Users/sasokan/Downloads/MyProject
```

Nothing happened. How can I call this groovy application using a script.

Comment: what happes, if you run it just in the shell?

Comment: When I just run it in the shell, groovy cmd is executed and code coverage report is generated.

Comment: Does it work if you put the full path to groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to run frankencover.it and had the same problem you did. I eventually found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315648/how-to-run-grunt-tasks-during-xcode-build-phase) on SO that lead me to a solution. I added the following before calling frankencover.it and it fixed the issue.

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

I will further note that even if you use the full path to groovy in the command frankencover.it will fail internally because it cannot find 'lcov' for the same reason.